# Выделенный сервер - выбор ос - ваш опыт и отзывы

Tags: php, сервер, debian, centos

В общем на выделенный сервер можно установить любую ОС.
Естественно, это будет Linux но вот какую выбрать?
Несколько лет я пользовался Centos OC b, претензий к ней не было.
Теперь мне предлагают debian.
Как думаете на сколько он лучше или хуже Centos?

И вот еще что, для меня теперь важно чтобы на сервере я мог установить Ruby  и другие интерпретаторы.
Как говорят на Centos ос - это не очень то возможно.

Также стоит учесть, что сервер будет предназначен для высоко нагруженного сайта с огромной посещаемостью и вот тут тоже очень важно чтобы он не слетал.

Т.е. ОС должна быть надежной.

Если Вы работали в крупных компаниях, напишите мне с какой конфигурацией серверов Вы работали и Ваши отзывы, сравнения и т.д.

Ссылки на надежные датацентры (хостинги) так же приветствуются.

Comment: AWS Amason - очень хорошая штука. Если амазон не падает, как это было на прошлой неделе, то все работает просто чудно. У них есть широкий выбор конфигураций машин, которые можно поднимать, а также есть различные географические зоны, в которых можно устанавливать серверы.

Comment: @dgfhgjljhjjd, что Вы подразумеваете под **высоко нагруженным**. Желательны **количественные** характеристики.

Comment: @stck, а на РутКоде начали отвечать?

Comment: @avp, не совсем понял вопрос :)

Comment: @stck, посмотрите на активность отвечающих (промежутки времени между вопросом и ответами на него) на РутКоде и все станет ясно.

Comment: да на руткоде можно годами ждать, как там не так активно как тут. Хотя тут тоже далеко до SO.

Answer (score 1):

Если к софту нет особых требований, типа наличия какой нить библиотеки которая есть не во всех репозитариях, то лучшим будет тот дистрибутив который вам хорошо знаком.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже не раз писали на подобные вопросы: выбирайте дистрибутив который лучший всего знает ваш админ/друг/жена.

Хотя бы сказали примерно какого типа проект(vopi, финансовая микротранзакция площадка, файлораздача порнухи), что для вас высокая нагрузка(у кого-то 300 рпс это уже очень высоко, а кому-то это фигня). Руби вы можете и на Slackware, и на Centos.

Comment: > дистрибутив, который знает ваша жена.

Ох...

Answer (score 1):

Как тут уже писали выше, лучшая ОСь та, которую знает ваш друг гуру. А вообще, именно для сервера не такой уж и большой выбор. Кстати вы можете его оценить исследуя вопрос по предустановленным ОСь больших ДЦ (типа ракспейс, лизвэб, софтлеер). Там присутствует выбор максимум из 5-7 вариантов. Среди них обычно RedHat, CentOS, Debian, Ubuntu, FreeBSD и Windows. Из чего можно понять, что два ОСи (рэдхет и центось) - почти братья близнецы, отличаются только поддержкой. Дебиан и убунту - тоже крайне родственные ос, отличающиеся отношением к версиям пакетов (я лично убунту на сервере постремался бы ставить), фря - это имхо для гиков и людей старой закалки, ну и винда без обсуждений. Все линукс ось, предлагаемые датацентрами, отлично подойдут под ваши требования, т.е. на них можно ставить без проблем руби и все что для него надо. Вопрос надежности и работе при хайлоаде будет зависеть только от прямоты рук обслуживающего админа и надежности самого датацентра. Если будет интересно, то можете почитать мое мнение о выборе [операционной системы для сервера](http://www.pub2me.net/server-os-election/).

Comment: @Pub2me, утверждение, что RedHat и CentOS отличаются *только* поддержкой не совсем верное. 

И дело не только в примерно полугодовом отставании.

Наш опыт (если брать RHEL) показывает, что   не все rpm-ы от CentOS (особенно кластерные) полностью работоспособны в RHEL.

Такое впечатление, что "красная шапочка" все же публикует не все свои изменения в сорсах.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение. Да, я согласен, что есть отставание в релизах пакетов по времени. На счет обратной совместимости, не могу ни подтвердить ни опровергнуть, т.к. мы уже давно отказались от RHEL (для нас не было смысла в платной подписке).